# How to modify Properties of Objects within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, redux, react-redux

First note that this is a question from my Redux code [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415221/react-redux-reducer-this-props-tasks-map-is-not-a-function-error).

Okay so lets say I want to edit the property of 'status' from "pending" to "deleted" to a specific property of an object within an array, how would I be able to do this using Object.Assign for the following examples:

**Example a: (notice the the array of objects is stored within an object itself)**

```js
const plan = {
  task: [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: "This is a task",
        status: "pending"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        description: "This is a second task",
        status: "pending"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Example b: (A simple array of elements whose elements are objects)**

```js
const task2 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: "This is a task",
        status: "pending"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        description: "This is a second task",
        status: "pending"
    }
]
```

Comment: good point, thanks! fixed it

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE** I'm using the code from your first question

Ok so firstly in your renderList function you'll need to include an onclick handler to register when a task is done:

```
renderList() {
  return this.props.tasks.tasks.map((task) => {
    if(task.status == "pending"){
        return (
          <li key={task.id}>
            {task.id} {task.description}
            <button type="button">Finish</button>
            <button type="button">Edit</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteTask(task.id)} type="button">Delete</button>
            </li>
          );
      }
  else return(
    <div key={task.id}>
      THIS TASK HAS BEEN DONE
    </div>
  );
```

});
}

Next, in your ActionIndex.js you should be recording WHICH action was selected, not just the message "deleted". SO change it to this:

```
export const deleteTaskAction = (taskId) => {
        return {
            type: 'DELETE_TASK',
            payload: taskId //pass on task id
        }
    };
```

Finally, in your reducer-tasks.js you should update the 'status' property of that specific list item when that action is dispatched (via the button click):

```
case 'DELETE_TASK':
    let newTasks = state.tasks.map( (task) => {
        if(task.id !== action.payload) {
            return task;
        }

        return Object.assign({}, task, {status : "deleted"});
    });

    const newState = Object.assign({}, state, {tasks : newTasks});
    return newState;
```

This should update the state and change the status of the selected task from "pending" to "deleted", which should trigger a re-render and change that element.

Let me know if you have any questions/issues

Comment: Ah that clears a lot up. However I get newState.tasks[action.payload] is undefined. I printed newState and it does copy the array of objects correctly. Not sure whats going there

Comment: If you print action.payload is that defined?

Comment: Yes its defined properly, it points to the correct object showing the id, description and status accordingly

Comment: action.payload should just equal the id, not the whole object

Comment: onClick={()=>this.props.deleteTask(task.id-1)} should pass the id only and payload: task in the action should pass on just the id. so in the reducer action.payload should just equal a number corresponding to the index

Comment: **WARNING**: the reducer example given is directly mutating the `tasks` object!  You need to make a copy for _every_ level of nesting involved in that data.  Please see the [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) page in the ["Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs for examples of how to properly do nested updates, including this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. The morphisms you're aiming to do are often referred as Lenses (which are a bigger grouping of morphisms, actually).

You can achieve it with pure JavaScript, for example:

```
// Return a new object with the very same structure as plan and an amended list of tasks
return Object.assign({}, plan, {
  tasks: plan.tasks.map(function (task) {
    // Map every existing task to a totally new object with the very same structure and a new status
    return Object.assign({}, task, { status: "deleted" })
  })
})
```

The second example is even easier to morph, check the following code:

```
return task2.map(function (task) {
  // Return a totally new object with the very same structure as task and a new status
  return Object.assign({}, task, { status: "deleted" });
})
```

What's more, there are also some libraries available out there that do exactly what you want, e.g. [nanoscope](http://www.kovach.me/nanoscope/getting-started.html)